# ConTeXt: Define word space dimensions

Tags: spacing, context

How would you define the length of a common word space? The word space length ConTeXt uses by itself is okay on the longer end, but way too short on the most compressed end.

The wiki entry for [`\setuptolerance`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuptolerance) suggests changing word spaces with:

```
\spaceskip .5em plus .25em minus .25em
```

So it sounds like there is a way to define the mean length, as well as maximum deviations for word spaces.

How would I use that setting throughout my document as the default word space?

Comment: Looking at the contextgarten page, it seems that you have to say `\setuptolerance[horizontal,space]`.

Comment: @egreg: but looking at the sources, it seems that `\setuptolerance[space]` only fixes `\spaceskip` and cannot change it.

Comment: @mbork Probably. But I don't think that setting `\spaceskip` is a good idea to begin with.

Comment: Agreed.  Sometimes, however, it might make sense (though `\emergencystretch` is probably usually the better way to go).  (This, either, does not have any high-level interface in ConTeXt, except for `\setuptolerance[stretch]`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try just putting something like

```
\spaceskip .5em plus .25em minus .25em
```

somewhere at the beginning of your document?  Short explanation: `\spaceskip` is (low-level) TeX parameter responsible exactly for that.

*Edit*: Notice that `em` depends on the *current* font, so you should first set the font (e.g. by `\setupbodyfont`) and only then issue the above command.

Also, strangely enough, after skimming through the ConTeXt (MkIV) sources, it seems to me that ConTeXt does not have a high-level interface for that (`\setraggedskips` is not what I'd call a "high-level" interface).  This has a benefit of making me quite sure that nothing (e.g. in `\starttext`) is going to change `\spaceskip`.

*Edit*: as egreg points out in the comments, changing `\spaceskip` is probably a bad idea; it might be better to use `\emergencystretch`, which (in case TeX cannot typeset a paragraph within its "badness" limits, even with hyphenation) is added to the "stretch" compoment of `\spaceskip`, so it is considered only, well, in *emergency* (bibliographies or twocolumn layout are two examples when one might want to use it - sparingly, of course!).

Notice that there is also `\xspaceskip`, which has a similar application as `\spaceskip`, but TeX uses it *at the end of the sentence* (unless `\frenchspacing` is in use).

Comment: It would be nice if everytime one states “Thing *x* is good/bad”, there would also be a short explanation **why** the writer thinks so. In this instance, it is left unclear whether setting `\spaceskip` is bad for setting global interword spacing, and if so, is it bad because there are `\fontdimen`s for that, or if it is bad because users should trust on the values provided by the font designer, or the underlying software? Or something else entirely?

Comment: @morbusg: very good point. I guess that fiddling with `\[x]spaceskip` is *bad*, because I assume that the font author already put the good-looking values into the font itself.  The only reason I can imagine now for changing it is to make typesetting narrow columns easier (without too much hyphenation/overfull boxes).  For that, `\emergencystretch` (and `\tolerance` & friends) seems better (well, less worse in fact: really better might be making your font smaller and/or setting the relevant portion of text `flushleft`).

Comment: while i agree that the font author probably defined a proper space width for the font, i still went with spaceskip and manual fiddling because context, as a rule, seems to see fit to slightly stretch or squash what the font author intended as a fixed value. thus, in cases, context OK'ed a word space value that was too damn short for the font. (=shorter than the font authors intended value)

Comment: Well, grepping the (MkIV) sources gave me certainty that ConTeXt seems *not* to change the font constant with respect to `\spaceskip` and its stretch and shrink components, unless you use verbatim-type environments (or `\setuptolerance[space]`).

Comment: but doesnt the default value 'verystrict' imply a slight tolerance for horizontal spacing? if not that, how would some lines end up with legible spaces and some with almost colliding words?

Comment: Yes, but by default the stretch and shrink components are positive.