# What settings for \[x]spaceskip would you suggest for Linux Libertine?

Tags: fonts, spacing, libertine

Quite contrary to [my own answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48202/defining-word-space-dimensions-in-context/48203#48203), I think that the default `\spaceskip` setting for Linux Libertine is rather unfortunate: seemingly, the shrink component is too high (and I end up getting to narrow spaces in tight lines).  So my question is: what setting would you recommend, and how it should be achieved (`\spaceskip` is global for all fonts, and I'd like only to change the shrink component of a space in Linux Libertine).  I am using XeLaTeX, and I don't know whether `\fontdimen`s work as in vanilla [pdf][e]tex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bringhurst suggests the values for body text: m/3 (even better if you can keep it at m/4) for interword space, m/2 for maximum space, and m/5 for minimum space. He also feels strongly against using the extra space between sentences, so assume `\frenchspacing`.

Setting the `\fontdimen`s work up until the math `\fontdimen`s.

`\spaceskip` is meant for temporarily changing the values, like removing the stretch and shrink components in `\raggedright`, which keeps interword space at its optimal value constantly.

So the settings could be represented in TeX form as:

```
% when the font you want is active:
\fontdimen2\font=.25em % or .3333em
\fontdimen3\font=\dimexpr.5em-\fontdimen2\font
\fontdimen4\font=\dimexpr\fontdimen2\font-.2em
```

Comment: Could you post the lines of code needed here, so that people can copy and paste it to their documents? :)

Comment: @Johannes: sure, done.