# ConTeXt: Increase word spacing in titles

Tags: spacing, context

How can I increase word spacing? Preferably, I’d like them to be of a constant size, as I need it to improve legibility in uppercase titles (when increasing the kerning, the words are too close together).

The only way I managed to do it [[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48202/context-define-word-space-dimensions)] [[3](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuptolerance)] was with `\spaceskip`, but that doesn’t work with nonbreaking spaces.

```tex
\setuppapersize [S6]

\starttext

  \setupalign[flushleft, nothyphenated, verytolerant]  
  \tfd\setupinterlinespace

  \setcharactercasing[WORD]
  \setcharacterkerning[extrakerning]
  \spaceskip .5em

  This is an~example.

\stoptext
```

[image: rendered output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConTeXt, unlike LaTeX and plain TeX, defines `~` as a Unicode non-breaking space (U+00A0) with catcode 12 ("other"), so you shouldn't be surprised it's not being treated as a space in the TeX sense. Instead you need `\nonbreakablespace` and, if this last command is to uncomfortable to write you may even do the following (better with grouping not to mess up things elsewhere):

```
%\begingroup
%...
\let~\nonbreakablespace
%...
%\endgroup
```